# when insert data to a interval partitioned table why the partition can't created

Tags: oracle, partitioning

When I create a partitioned table by range interval and create the first partition manually as the SQL shows.

```
  CREATE TABLE "HDEVAMP"."POS_DATA" 
   (    "START_DATE" DATE, 
    "STORE_ID" NUMBER, 
    "INVENTORY_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "QTY_SOLD" NUMBER(3,0)
   ) 
  PARTITION BY RANGE ("START_DATE") INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
 (PARTITION "POS_DATA_P27"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2018-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd')));
```

why the partitioned was not create automatically when I insert the data whose partition key is 20171231.

```
     insert into pos_data values (TO_DATE('2017-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD'),1,110,12);
insert into pos_data values (TO_DATE('2018-01-31','YYYY-MM-DD'),1,110,12);
commit;
```

it just create one partition POS_DATA_P27 to store all above two data,not create a partition to store the data for "2017-12-31"

```
"TABLE_NAME","COMPOSITE","PARTITION_NAME","SUBPARTITION_COUNT","HIGH_VALUE","HIGH_VALUE_LENGTH","PARTITION_POSITION","TABLESPACE_NAME","PCT_FREE","PCT_USED","INI_TRANS","MAX_TRANS","INITIAL_EXTENT","NEXT_EXTENT","MIN_EXTENT","MAX_EXTENT","MAX_SIZE","PCT_INCREASE","FREELISTS","FREELIST_GROUPS","LOGGING","COMPRESSION","COMPRESS_FOR","NUM_ROWS","BLOCKS","EMPTY_BLOCKS","AVG_SPACE","CHAIN_CNT","AVG_ROW_LEN","SAMPLE_SIZE","LAST_ANALYZED","BUFFER_POOL","FLASH_CACHE","CELL_FLASH_CACHE","GLOBAL_STATS","USER_STATS","IS_NESTED","PARENT_TABLE_PARTITION","INTERVAL","SEGMENT_CREATED","INDEXING","INMEMORY","INMEMORY_PRIORITY","INMEMORY_DISTRIBUTE","INMEMORY_COMPRESSION","INMEMORY_DUPLICATE"
"POS_DATA","NO","POS_DATA_P27",0,"TO_DATE(' 2018-02-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')",83,1,"SYSTEM",10,40,1,255,65536,1048576,1,2147483645,2147483645,,1,1,"YES","DISABLED","",,,,,,,,,"DEFAULT","DEFAULT","DEFAULT","NO","NO","NO","","NO","YES","ON","DISABLED","","","",""
```

Comment: Please don't paste pictures. Describe your problem as text. What is your partition interval? Show your insert statement and show why you think the record is in wrong partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a partition `LESS THAN 2018-02-01 00:00:00` which means: everything earlier than 2018-02-01 goes into that partition.

20171231, i.e. `2017-12-31` is obviously earlier than 2018-02-01, so what do you expect?

Oracle will create new partition for values **after** 2018-02-01.

Comment: Sorry for using the picture，I need the oracle create a new partiton to store the data 20171231，just like it create partition after 2018-02-01 for every month，As the fact is some old data may insert to the partition table for special use sometimes. can I create a partitioned table whose first partition is from 1999 or earlier（depend on our need）？

Comment: Yes you can run for example `VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '1900-01-01')`. If you insert for instance value for 2018-02-01 then Oracle will create a new partition - just a single one for that date, not hundreds of empty ones. Otherwise you would have to use [Splitting into Multiple Partitions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-01C14320-0D7B-48BE-A5AD-003DDA761277.htm)

Comment: ，Thanks a lot，very helpful